# Updated Jquery post not returning data

Tags: jquery, post

I have a script that is a form that allows you to select values from a drop down and a date which is sent to a processing page and returns the values to populate the appropriate text boxes according to those two value combination.

It was built using Jquery 1.7.1 and I am trying to extend this form but for some reason when I use the latest library (Jquery 3.1.1) and I also have to update the Bootstrap.js to the latest version but now the callback is not returning. I don't see any errors and the values are passed correctly.

Using Jquery 1.7.1 it returns just fine just not with the latest libraries.

This is my code:

```
$.post("http://url.com", 
            { action: "data", ID: ID },
            function(data){


                var fieldListing = ''
                for (var key in data) 
                {
                    var field = data[key];
                    var fieldName = field["Label"];
                    var fieldLabel = field["Designated Name"];
                    var fieldCharMax = field["Character Max"];
                    var fieldRows = Math.ceil(fieldCharMax/120);
                    var fieldOrder = field["Display Order"];


                    $('<div/>').attr({
                        id: fieldName + '_div',
                        name: fieldName + '_div'
                    }).appendTo("#field_listing");

                    // append a SPAN to new DIV
                    $('<span class="item_label" />').attr({
                        id: fieldName + '_span',
                        name: fieldName + '_span'
                    }).appendTo('#' + fieldName + '_div');

                    // append field label to new SPAN
                    $('<label for="' + fieldName + '">' + fieldLabel + ' (Max Length: ' + fieldCharMax + ')</label>').appendTo('#' + fieldName + '_span');


                    var field_data = "";
                    <script runat="server"> 
                    if (action == 'edit') {
                    </script>   
                    if ( row_data != null ) {
                        field_data = row_data[fieldName];   
                    }
                    <script runat="server"> 
                    }
                    </script>


                    $('<textarea>' + field_data + '</textarea>').attr({
                        maxlength: fieldCharMax,
                        rows: fieldRows,
                        cols: '135',
                        name: fieldName,
                        id: fieldName,
                        'class': 'span12'
                    }).appendTo('#' + fieldName + '_div');


                    fieldListing = fieldListing + fieldName + ',';

                }


                $('<input type="hidden"/>').attr({
                        id: 'field_names',
                        name: 'field_names',
                        value: fieldListing
                    }).appendTo('#field_listing');


            }, "json"
        );
```

Comment: If you plan to use the latest libraries, you need to use the jQuery Migrate plugin.

Comment: That solved the issue. I just saw that the $.browser was deprecated but I wasn't using it but it must some of the Date picker functions.